# Can't update row in Microsoft Access

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, cursor, ms-access

I am trying to fill an empty column with unique number for every data, I use the following code:

```
import arcpy
my_input = []
column = "REGION_ID"
column1 = "MUNICIPAL_ID"
column2 = "INSTR_ID"
column3 = "DISTRICT_ID"
searchcursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("house_point")
fields = ['ind']
index = 1
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor('D:/yvareli.mdb/house_point', fields)

for row in searchcursor:
    my_input.append(int(str(row.getValue(column)) + str(row.getValue(column1)) + str(row.getValue(column2)) + str(row.getValue(column3))))


for i in range(len(my_input)):
    cursor.insertRow([index])
    index += 1
del cursor
```

but instead of updating existing row, it just creates empty copies for every column and adds unique values in new rows.

Comment: You left out the `da` in your SearchCursor and used `InsertCursor` not `UpdateCursor`.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have presented?

Comment: I'm using arcmap

Comment: When I run this code, instead to update row, it creates new one and as I have 30000 recording, after executing the script, it will be 60000

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using InsertCursor that's why it's inserting new rows. Try using UpdateCursor.

```
import arcpy
column = "REGION_ID"
column1 = "MUNICIPAL_ID"
column2 = "INSTR_ID"
column3 = "DISTRICT_ID"
ind = 'ind'
fields = [column, column1, column2, column3, ind]

cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('D:/yvareli.mdb/house_point', fields)

for row in cursor:
    value = int(str(row[0]) + str(row[1]) + str(row[2]) + str(row[3])))
    row[-1] = value
    cursor.updateRow(row)


del cursor
```

Comment: Thank you, worked, god bless you

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark it as a correct answer.